# Python: How to read line from file which has two line spaces in between

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, readfile

I am trying to read a file which has format like below: It has two '\n' space in between every line.

```
Great tool for healing your life--if you are ready to change your beliefs!<br /><a href="http


Bought this book for a friend. I read it years ago and it is one of those books you keep forever. Love it!


I read this book many years ago and have heard Louise Hay speak a couple of times.  It is a valuable read...
```

I am using below python code to read the line and convert it into Dataframe:

```
open_reviews = open("C:\\Downloads\\review_short.txt","r",encoding="Latin-1" ).read()
documents = []
for r in open_reviews.split('\n\n'):
    documents.append(r)

df = pd.DataFrame(documents)
print(df.head())
```

The output I am getting is as below:

```
0  I was very inspired by Louise's Hay approach t...
1  \n You Can Heal Your Life by 
2  \n I had an older version
3  \n I love Louise Hay and
4  \n I thought the book was exellent
```

Since I used two (\n), it gets appended at beginning of each line. Is there any other way to handle this, so that I get output as below:

```
0  I was very inspired by Louise's Hay approach t...
1  You Can Heal Your Life by 
2  I had an older version
3  I love Louise Hay and
4  I thought the book was exellent
```

Answer (score 2):

This appends every non-blank line.

```
filename = "..."
lines = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)

>>> lines
['Great tool for healing your life--if you are ready to change your beliefs!<br /><a href="http',
 'Bought this book for a friend. I read it years ago and it is one of those books you keep forever. Love it!',
 'I read this book many years ago and have heard Louise Hay speak a couple of times.  It is a valuable read...']

lines = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=['my_text'])
>>> lines
                                             my_text
0  Great tool for healing your life--if you are r...
1  Bought this book for a friend. I read it years...
2  I read this book many years ago and have heard...
```

Comment: This answer is, though longer, more preferable as it doesn't read in the whole file in the for loop. Calling `readlines()` or `strip()` will read the entire file into memory.

Comment: But, this is better way with out knowing size of file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .stip() method. It will remove any unnecessary whitespace characters from the beginning or end of a string.

You can use it like this:

```
for r in open_review.split('\n\n'):
    documents.append(r.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `readlines()` and clean the line with `strip()`.

```
filename = "C:\\Downloads\\review_short.txt"
open_reviews = open(filename, "r", encoding="Latin-1")
documents = []
for r in open_reviews.readlines():
    r = r.strip()  # clean spaces and \n
    if r:
        documents.append(r)
```